# Revit API: Custom ModelLine

Tags: c#, .net, revit, revit-api

We're developing a plugin for revit to determine sections of a construction plan.

Therefore we need something like model lines, but they need to be bound to a certain level. We also need to add custom Properties to these elements.

What should I use? Are model lines ok? How can properties be added to them? How can they be bound to a certain level?

Comment: What do you mean by "need something like model lines"?  Do you want to create model lines in your document or detect existing lines?

Answer (score 1):

If the data you need to store is simple enough to store as family parameters, you could create a generic line based family. The family would contain a model line and parameters to store the required data. Your addin can then calculate the required sketchplanes and place the family as you would the standard model lines. The user will then have easy access to the associated data through the built-in properties window  even when you addin is not installed.